# Datapoint starting and ending in API

Tags: json, api

I am confused where does the a datapoint start and end. Please guide me. Thanks. [Here](http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot) is the API.

One trick is to search for "id" in the text. Please let me know other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This API is called JSON API. To view contents of JSON API, you can use [this tool](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/7f7f1e). It shows the results in a tree viewer, making it easy to understand for anyone.